# DllImport params on attribute

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport

Can I instead of the name library, substitute parameter?

for example:

**Now**

```
[DllImport("First.dll")]
public static extern bool Info([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] ref string result);
```

**Want**

```
private static string dllName = "Second.dll"

[DllImport(dllName)]
public static extern bool Info([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] ref string result);
```

Comment: Did you test it? You can find the answer out in a few seconds by trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can use a const but not a variable.

If you have a good reason (i.e. not simply avoiding repeated declarations) you can [do it dynamically](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/06/typesafe-getprocaddress.aspx) by p/invoking `LoadLibrary` -> `GetProcAddress` then calling the export via `UnmanagedFunctionPointer`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much a question about `DllImport` and p/invoke as one about the C# attributes language feature. You can answer the question purely with knowledge of attributes. And the key knowledge is that the parameters to attributes must be constant. Since these parameters are evaluated at compile time, they cannot be variables.

So the answer is that the code in your question does not compile because you are trying to use a variable as a parameter to an attribute. You can change the parameter to be a constant, like this:

```
private const string dllName = "Second.dll";

[DllImport(dllName)]
....
```